# How do we generate, random numbers between 300 and 3000 using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, random

Random numbers between a range of numbers.

I have tried

```
np.random.rand()
np.random.rand(a,b)
np.random.rand(a)
```

and many more combinations

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a random integer using:
`numpy.random.randint(a,b)`
Where a is the minimum value and b is the maximum value

Adding the argument:
`numpy.random.randint(a,b, size=x)`
Allows you to generate a list of numbers, with length x

Edit* Technically it isn't a list, it is a one-dimensional matrix.

Comment: or `np.random.uniform` for floats instead of integers...